# Hibernate how to transform Criteria to HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

I have a problem with a Criteria query.

In an other method I use HQL query in order to remove some objects in database.
The query works.

In another method I do, actually, Criteria query which get objects.
When i get objects , they are not synchronized to the database.

So 
1. How synchronized this criteria query in roder to get REAL objects?
2. If 1. is not possible, i want to transform Criteria query to HQL

Here my criteria query:

```
    final Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(ObjectDao.class);
    if (clientName != null && clientName.length() > 0) {
        crit.createAlias("objectType.client", "client");
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("client.name", clientName));
    }
    if (objectType != null && objectType.length() > 0) {
        crit.createAlias("objectType", "objectType");
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("objectType.type", objectType));
    }
    final List<ObjectDao> ret = crit.list();
```

And HQl transformed query which dont work

```
    String hqlQuery = "select ObjectDao where objectType.client.name = :clientName";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hqlQuery)
    // .setParameter("objectList", objectType)
            .setParameter("clientName", clientName);
    final List<ObjectDao> ret2 = query.list();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using some sort of Hibernate level 2 cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are  using Level 2 cache. If so this will not work either.

```
select o from ObjectDao o where o.objectType.client.name = :clientName
```

Comment: yes the query works but object are still in session evan if i use HQL :(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're executing a query such as

```
delete from Client where ...
```

and then execute a Criteria query which returns ObjectDaos still having a client that you just deleted.

If that's right, then it's expected behavior. DML-style queries (i.e. update and delete queries) bypass the session. This means that if some object that you deleted was already loaded in the session before the delete query, Hibernate won't delete them from the session, and the session won't reflect the actual state of the database.

Use Session.delete to delete your objects, and make sure to maintain your object graph in memory.

Or flush and clear the session after the delete query.

Comment: `session.clear();session.flush();` are already done after HQL delete but objects are still here .

I have done a HQL delete in order to improve perfs which where not very good with Criteria for delete.

Comment: Here the processes:

1. First of all, users can display objects to delete
So i was doing this with Criteria and now with HQL query

2. Users see the objects, if he is agree, hecan remove objects when he push the "delete button
If he is not agree if can enter new parameters in the form and click in "display' button to see otehrs objects that he possibly want to remove

I have change delete Criteria to HQL in order to improve petfs, HQL delete is better in order to remove many many of objects
But now the display step is not good :(

If after the HQL get i add clear/close: issue! :(thx